# How to jump to mark in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

What variable or function I need to use to jump to the place of the marker set by `set-mark-command` `C-SPC` using `goto-char`?

```
(defun jump-to-mark ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char <WHAT PUT HERE>))
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `exchange-point-and-mark` command (bound to <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd>) jumps to the mark, and puts the current position (*i.e.* just before the jump) on top of the mark ring.

A side effect is that the region is activated. You can pass a prefix argument (i.e. press <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd>) to avoid this.

---

As mentioned in other answers, another way to navigate in the mark ring consists in using <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-SPC</kbd>, which jumps to the mark and removes it from the mark ring. Repeating the command thus makes you navigate through all successive mark positions in reverse-chronological order. However, mark positions visited that way are lost.

A sibling of <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-SPC</kbd> is <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-SPC</kbd>, which is very similar but acts on the *global* mark ring, which stores successive marks *in all buffers*.

Comment: `C-u C-SPC` has the same behaviour as `C-x C-SPC`: it pops the mark of the mark ring, meaning the mark is not available anymore. This might (or might not, that's up to you) be an undesirable side-effect. The difference between `C-u C-SPC` and `C-x C-SPC` is that the former acts on the mark ring (local to the current buffer), whereas the latter acts on the global mark ring (where all successive mark positions in all buffers are stored).

Answer (score 6):

I just found that it's `mark-marker` so my function to jump should be:

```
(defun jump-to-mark ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (mark-marker)))
```

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is

> pop-global-mark is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `simple.el'.
>
> It is bound to C-x C-@, C-x C-SPC.
>
> (pop-global-mark)
>
> Pop off global mark ring and jump to the top location.

Another option is C-x C-x which runs the command `exchange-point-and-mark`.

Comment: Yes, but this command pops the mark off the mark ring, meaning it is not available anymore afterwards. This might be an undesirable side-effect for the OP.

Answer (score 3):

To stay inline with your original code, you can just put `(mark)` instead of the WHAT PUT HERE, and it'll work. This is because `(mark)` returns the position of the mark (just like `(point)` returns the location integer of point).

```
(defun jump-to-mark ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (mark)))
```

Comment: +1 for answering question also maybe using mark here is ever so slightly more idiomatic than using mark-marker although they seem interchangeable in this particular context.